# Ajax image upload gives me error of 405 (Method Not Allowed) and origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: ajax, thumbor

I'm trying to upload an image to the [Thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor) server using Ajax POST.But it gives me error of **405 (Method Not Allowed)** and **origin has been blocked by CORS policy**

Here is my AJAX POST code to upload image:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Ajax upload</title>
<input type="file" id="upload-files" name="upload-files">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upload-files").change(function () {
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("media", "../218eLEn0fuL.png");

        var settings = {
          "async": true,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "http://upload.localhost.com/image",
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Content-Type": "image/png",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Host": "upload.localhost.com",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
          },
          "processData": false,
          "contentType": false,
          "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
          "data": form
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But this gives me error of like this:
- OPTIONS http://upload.localhost.com/image **405 (Method Not Allowed)**
- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://upload.localhost.com/image' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Could anyone help me out to resolve this issues?

Thanks